# Need assistance with Notepad++ to remove the last column from a huge ascii file

Tags: notepad++, multiple-columns

Good day.

I need to delete the last column from a huge file. The last column could be a a word, digit, symbol or sentence in quotes.  I've tried `(\w+).$` and `(\w+)?.$` and several others which will remove single words or digits but not those linked by underscore words containing special characters ie: `,.+_-` etc.
Because the parameters are of varied length, I can't use Shift-Alt to block mark and edit the file.

Original contents:

```
parm1 parm2 parameter_with_different_length false
parm1 parm2 parameter_with_different_length 0
parm1 parm2 parameter_with_different_length 1
parm1 parm2 parameter_with_different_length off
parm1 parm2 parameter_with_different_length "INVITE MESSAGE"
parm1 parm2 parameter_with_different_length ""
parm1 parm2 parameter_with_different_length /tmp/audit/out
parm1 parm2 parameter_with_different_length +12345@mysite.com
parm1 parm2 parameter_with_different_length hss_ctr
parm1 parm2 parameter_with_different_length +g.poc.groupad
parm1 parm2 parameter_with_different_length S1AP-MISC
parm1 parm2 parameter_with_different_length 3002,3004,3007,4002
```

Expecting:

```
parm1 parm2 parameter_with_different_length
parm1 parm2 parameter_with_different_length
parm1 parm2 parameter_with_different_length
parm1 parm2 parameter_with_different_length
parm1 parm2 parameter_with_different_length
parm1 parm2 parameter_with_different_length
parm1 parm2 parameter_with_different_length
parm1 parm2 parameter_with_different_length
parm1 parm2 parameter_with_different_length
parm1 parm2 parameter_with_different_length
parm1 parm2 parameter_with_different_length
parm1 parm2 parameter_with_different_length
```

Please advise.

Regards,
Bjoern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\h(?:"[^"\r\n]+"|\S+)$`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\h              # horizontal space
(?:             # non capture group
"               # a double quote
[^"\r\n]+       # 1 or more any character that is not a quote or linebreak
"               # a double quote
|               # OR
\S+             # 1 or more any non space character
)               # end group
$               # end of line
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thank you Toto, it works perfectly.  Also thanks for the concise explanation.